# transform:rotate is blurring image

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, transform

How is it possible to apply rotate transformation without losing quality?
I've tried add translateZ(0) but it doesn't help anyway.
This is example:

```css
svg {
     background-color: rgb(93, 193, 93);
}
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(1deg);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <image xlink:href="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png" width="60" height="60" x="90"/>
  <image xlink:href="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png" width="60" height="60" x="160" transform="rotate(1)"/>
</svg>
<div>
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png"/>
  <img src="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png" class="rotated"/>
</div>
```

Comment: you can turn it off via the image-rendering CSSS property https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering but I doubt you'd like the results.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the response! This property doesn't help, I'm trying and I see effect only for 'image-rendering: pixelated;' but it looks askew(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg width="400" height="100">
  <image x="50" y="20" xlink:href="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png" width="60" height="60" />
  <image x="120" y="20" transform="rotate(-90, 150, 50)" xlink:href="https://s11.postimg.org/vzvfu6osz/chip_25.png" width="60" height="60" />
</svg>
```

What's about rotating with the svg transform attribute? There you can set the rotation center as additional parameters.

The rotated image looks really fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a low resolution (60x60) icon and rotating it by a tiny amount.  You will have a small detrimental effect due to interpolation/anti-aliasing.

If you use a higher resolution icon (eg. 120x120) as your original image. Then render that at 60x60 with rotation, you should find it looks better then the low res one.

Comment: Good point! Thanks! I've tried to do it and doesn't help. So, i see that no way to do it better for bitmaps, my understanding is that need to use SVG.

Comment: It may be better than a bitmap. Hopefully it is. But if you plan on having lines that are one degree off the horizontal or vertical, the result may not be all that much better. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

you should read more about affine [transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).

Comment: Why? There is no information about image quality after applying transformation